# The trimutri gunas are mentioned in devi bhagavat purana

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana

The trimiutri gunas are mentioned in devi bhagavat purana . the paramatma have three gunas which taken bodys

Comment: Hello. Welcome to HSE. What is the question? please explain it.

Comment: Do you want to say - "The three gunas are mentioned in Devi Bhagavat purana . And, the paramatma manifested in 3 forms of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva, by adopting three gunas, viz, Rajas, Sattva and Tamas " @Pasham Vishnu Vardhan Goud